# SQL not returning data

Tags: mysql, sql, go

When I query a MySQL database for rows I just insert using the `database/sql` Go package, I don't get any data back.

For example:

```
db := sql.Open("mysql", host)

_, err = db.Query("INSERT INTO users(id, name) VALUES(1, 'John')")

if err != nil{
         panic(err)
}

rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John'")

if err != nil{
         panic(err)
}

var id int
results.Scan(&id)

fmt.Println(id)
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: What is `results`? That's undefined in the code you've pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `rows.Next` to advance the internal pointer to the first result, before you call `Scan`.

Typically your code should look something like this:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE name='John'")

// ...

for rows.Next() {
         rows.Scan(&id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over rows using rows.Next(), then scan the value into the required variable.